# Why should I avoid using ClassType in application code?

Tags: delphi, oop

The Delphi online documentation says

> "Avoid using [ClassType](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.TObject.ClassType) in application code".

However there are many places where a class type is needed. For example when a program uses the class System.Contnrs.[TClassList](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Contnrs.TClassList), I need the ClassType of an object to pass it in the parameter of IndexOf().

What is the reason behind this recommendation in the ClassType documentation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The most obvious reason why this advice is given is for programmers that want to write code like this:

```
if obj.ClassType = TStringList then
  ....
```

That condition will only evaluate true if the object's class is `TStringList`. However, very commonly you would want the conditional code to run for `TStringList` and any descendents. In which case you write:

```
if obj is TStringList then
  ....
```

If you need to know what class an instance is, then `ClassType` is what you should use. If you are maintaining a list of classes in a `TClassList` instance, then feel free to use `ClassType` to obtain the meta class of an instance.

Comment: another reason would be a `obj = nil` case :-)  The `is` and `as` operators do check for nil, but direct function call would probably not